# Django: is the command line the only way to access the database API?

Tags: python, django

My Google-fu is failing me. I'm doing [this tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) and it wants me to define important-looking functions while using the command line shell. If this is the only way, I'll do it, but it seems inefficient (make one typo and you have to redefine the whole thing). Also I thought that shell sessions were mostly for testing things out, but it looks like the things I'm defining here are more permament. Where can I find a record of the functions I've defined, etc.? Or am I misunderstanding what they're wanting me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, where are you getting this idea that the tutorial you linked to asks you to write functions in the shell?

I just went through the tutorials again and the shell isn't even brought up in Tutorial 2, 3, and 4. It briefly appears in tutorial 1 but no functions are written.

Tutorial 3 goes through the process of building a simple view. First define urls to route a request to your view function, start returning some raw text, then start using real HTML templates.

So yes, you're misunderstanding what they want you to do : )

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought they wanted me to do that in the API itself which made no sense. I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the shell is only for trying things out. You can't define persistent functions there. You do those in Python files which are run by your server.

Sounds like you need a basic Python tutorial - see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) for a list.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought the general rule was, and I've written non-Django Python programs before. I just can't figure out how I'm supposed to access the Django database API except through the command-line shell.

Answer (score 0):

you've mentioned 'access the Django database API' two times.  What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to define models? Make Queries on already defined models? Some more information could help us help you.

Comment: I was being stupid and thought the tutorial wanted me to access the database API for some indiscernible reason, but really it just wanted me to keep editing the view I already had open. Everything's good now :)